# Convert binary string to hexadecimal string C

Tags: c, string, binary, char, hex

As the title said I was interested in the best way to convert a binary string to a hexadecimal string in C. The binary string is 4 bits at most so converting into a single hexadecimal char would be best.

Thanks for any help, I'm not sure if there's something built in to make this easier so don't have my own attempt to post yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? Fastest? Simplest code?

Comment: @samgak Sorry, simplest without being terribly poor performance wise. Not too worried about performance. Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad and is not on topic. StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: @2501 As someone new to C I was really interested in whether there's something built in to make this easier, as opposed to writing my own function. Thanks for your opinion though

Comment: convert binary string to int with atoi with base 2 and then int to hex string with sprintf

Comment: @JustinChand That wasn't my opinion, you question is objectively off-topic. You never ask a question, but allude that you're looking for code. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @2501 Sorry I missed a '?' and 'how to'. Deliberate misinterpretation isn't required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strtol` to convert the binary string to an integer, and then `sprintf` to convert the integer to a hex string:

```
char* binaryString = "1101";

// convert binary string to integer
int value = (int)strtol(binaryString, NULL, 2);

// convert integer to hex string
char hexString[12]; // long enough for any 32-bit value, 4-byte aligned
sprintf(hexString, "%x", value);

// output hex string
printf(hexString);
```

Output:

```
d
```

If it's guaranteed to be a single hexadecimal character just take `hexString[0]`.