# Converting a binary string to integer

Tags: c, int, strtol

When I try and convert my binary string to int I am receiving a couple of mistakes that I can not figure out.  First I am reading from a file and the leading zeros are not showing up when I convert and the new line is showing zero.

This code I am using from this questions: [Convert binary string to hexadecimal string C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041030/convert-binary-string-to-hexadecimal-string-c)

```
char* binaryString[100];

// convert binary string to integer
int value = (int)strtol(binaryString, NULL, 2);

//output string as int
printf("%i \n",value)
```

My txt file and what I am expecting as an output:

```
00000000

000000010001001000111010
00000000000000000000000000000001
101010111100110100110001001001000101
```

What I get:

```
0
0
70202
1
-1127017915
```

Comment: The 2nd argument of `strtol()` is useful for error detection/recovery.

Comment: "First I am reading from a file and the leading zeros are not showing up" --> Why is not showing leading zeros considered a problem?

Comment: To get the same exact output text as input use `printf("%s\n", binaryString)`

Comment: `101010111100110100110001001001000101`  is a 36-bit number without a sign.  Do expect to store that unchanged in an signed integer less than 37-bit?  `int` is often 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *binaryString[100];
```

// You are creating an array of pointers in this scenario, use `char binaryString[100]` instead;

```
int value = (int)strtol(binaryString, NULL, 2);
```

// `101010111100110100110001001001000101` Is a 36 bit number, `int` (in most implementations) is 32 bit. use `long long` (64 bit in visual c++) as type and `strtoll` as function instead.

```
printf("%i \n",value)
```

Must be `printf("%lld \n", value)`.

In summary:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h" // required for strtoll

int main(void)
{
    char str[100] = "101010111100110100110001001001000101";
    long long val = 0;
    val = strtoll(str, NULL, 2);
    //output string as int
    printf("%lld \n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
char* binaryString[100];
```

Is declaring an array of 100 char pointers (or 100 strings).  You probably meant this to declare a buffer of 100 characters to be interpreted as a single string:

```
char binaryString[100];
```

Answer (score 0):

if im understanding this correctly you want to take a binary string so ones and zeros and convert it to a Hex string so 0-F, if so the problem is with the Write not the Convert, you specified '%i' as the written value format, what you need to do for hex is specify '%x'

Change this "printf("%i \n",value)" to "printf("%x\n",value)"